# How can I find CSS selector from a HTML matching a specific criteria?

Tags: javascript, python, css, parsing, html-parsing

I want to parse any given link and see if there are any CSS selectors whose attributes maybe partially or completely matching a specific keyword.
If my keyword is print, I want every CSS selector in the given link that has print anywhere in it, it maybe present at either the name, id or class or anywhere.

For example if the link I give gets me the following html:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="testprintrandom">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p id="randomstackoverflowrandomtext">Lorem ipsum</p>
        <a href="/randomLink/rancheque324">Good Bye</a>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email address">
    </div>
</body>
```

If my keyword is "print" then I should get the selector "p.testprintrandom" as a part of it's class name had print in it. similarly if my keyword is "stackoverflow" I should get the id "randomstackoverflowrandomtext" as a part of the id has stackoverflow inside it. similarly if my keyword is email then I should get the CSS selector for the input tag as the placholder had email in it.

First off I want to know if this is possible and if so how can I achieve this, is there any specific library or framework I can use?

I will later be using the obtained selectors with puppeteer if that should influence the answer in any way.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind doing this? Wouldn't it be easier to just add a specific class to the elements you need to select?

Comment: @rblarsen I will only be parsing websites here thus I can't do so, I won't be creating any elements here but using already created websites so I wanted to parse them based on the selector names. I will later be using the selectors obtained with headless browsers(puppeteer) thus I want the selectors.

Comment: You first would need to be able to extract all possible CSS selectors from a piece of HTML. After that it is just a question of string matching. But that first step is clearly the difficult bit, there are so many possible selectors. Why not check any CSS files, or internal styles, that are linked to the HTML, isn't that easier? After all, they already have the selectors in them.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I really hadn't thought of that! but I would be in trouble if they happen to use inline styling or something similar though.

Comment: There are some basic parsers for HTML in PHP, you can use them to extract the styles tag. See, for instance: http://nimishprabhu.com/top-10-best-usage-examples-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html

Answer (score 1):

Just a example/sample:

According to your question that you want to find an element with respect to its css matching selector see this:
[image]

suppose that i have a button with css = `class="lx-stream-show-more__button gel-long-primer-bold"`and i want to get the element matching with `gel-long-primer-bold`as in the end of css so i would do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

bt = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.gel-long-primer-bold')
```

here in `bt` i will get all elements that ends matching with `gel-long-primer-bold` css in it. Then will perform further actions.

**Note:** It is just a example to give you idea. You will get better answer if you provide your code or provide better explanation to your question.

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: what if my keyword happens to be just "long-primer" and not "gel-long-primer-bold". I still want to get the selector as long-primer is a part of the class name. That is my problem here, I don't have a specific id so I am searching for all possible matches.